# Unable to get input from RPi3 GPIO serial, crashes when using RX pin

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, c++, wiringpi

I have a sensor which spits out information via serial and I am trying to receive that input on my Raspberry Pi 3 via the serial RX (BCM pin 15).

I'm using the wiringPi library in a C++ program to use the serial interface. I'm fairly certain that my code that reads from the serial device is correct because I was able to use USB serial devices fine.

I am trying to use `/dev/ttyAMA0` in the `openSerial` function, which can be opened successfully. I just can't seem to get any data.

Basically:

- I'm using the BCM pin numbers in wiringPi (`wiringPiSetupGpio`)
- I have uart enabled in raspi-config
- I have confirmed that I'm getting output from my sensor
- I've double checked my wiring
- I know my code works with USB serial devices

I know it could be something as simple as one wrong connection, but I've checked thoroughly and had some fresh sets of eyes look at it too, so I feel like there might be something else that I'm missing.

Not sure if related:

When I have the RX pin connected to my sensor for a few minutes, the Pi will eventually freeze. I'm not sure exactly what happens when it freezes. My ssh connection will freeze, but I can still see the ethernet light blink when I type.

I was thinking this might be caused by a short or overvoltage, but the behavior seems quite odd.

**Edit:**
I have everything working now. I removed the console and kbdg sections from my cmdline.txt, and added `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` to my config.txt. I have narrowed the freezing issue to the ethernet port.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem with freezing when I had a sensor sending data on the serial link and had forgotten to disable serial console login.  The system became incredibly busy attempting and rejecting console logins on the serial link.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll make sure that's disabled. If that's the case, then the freezing might be due to the huge amount of data going into  `/dev/ttyAMA0`, which should be the bluetooth module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do **NOT** use `/dev/ttyAMA0` which is connected to Bluetooth (by default).

**Use** `/dev/serial0` which is connected to default serial port, even if you take any of the measures to modify behaviour.

Comment: I had been referencing some older guides which specified using `/dev/ttyAMA0`. The other reason for using that was because the only other device that I could see was `/dev/ttyS0`. This [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3) clears up my understanding. It looks like the most straightforward way is just to disable bluetooth.

Comment: @sealj553 There is **absolutely NO reason** to use anything other than `/dev/serial?` in a recent OS. Your question is lacking any real information. I usually assume people are running the latest Raspbian (or penultimate after a new release) without undisclosed changes. `/dev/serial*` has existed in normal distributions and are links setup by `udev` on boot. See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: Understood. I am running a jessie image from October by the way, I'll be upgrading to stretch anyways. Last time I was using GPIO serial, I had been using a RPi 1B, so I hadn't known about the change to `/dev/serial`. Yeah, that's the same link I referenced.